May one answer "kedusha" or kaddish during shmone esrei if holding at "shema kolenu", specifically?
Is it permissible to recite the prayers of "kedusha" or "kaddish" during the Shmone Esrei prayer if one is pausing at the "Shema Koleinu" section, where one may engage in personal supplication and direct communication with Hashem?

No, because those are not supplications and would constitute an interruption. See Yalkut Yosef 104:4:

העומד בתפלה באמצע ברכת שמע קולנו, ושמע מהצבור שעונים "יהא שמיה רבה
מברך", אינו רשאי להפסיק לענות עמהם, ואף על פי שרשאי כל אדם לשאול צרכיו
באמצע ברכת שומע תפלה, מכל מקום עניית "יהא שמיה רבה מברך" אינה מענין
שאלת צרכיו, ונחשבת להפסק


This is not wrong, but there's something more fundamental at play than it lets on. The phrase יהא שמיה isn't a request, but it could certainly be worked into a request, like תן שלום לעמו המקלסים לו בכל יום יהא שמיה רבא מברך. But even doing that and timing it with the tzibbur isn't the same as answering (cf OC 109:3)
